# Android DownloadManager ETag support

Tags: android, etag, download-manager

[There](http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2011/05/18/xperia%E2%84%A2-game-developer-tip-1-a-download-should-automatically-resume-if-the-connection-fails/) is info that Android's DownloadManager support ETags.
Okay, I have a server with ETag support (e.g. DropBox). When I'm trying to download a file DownloadManager creates a new one and appends a number to the local filename (e. g. file.zip, file-1.zip, file-2.zip etc.). Is there a way not to download an existing file with same ETag? My app ***will*** be downloading huge files so I don't want to reload them every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way not to download existing file with same ETag?

You are the one requesting the downloads. You need to determine what files should and should not be downloaded. AFAIK, `DownloadManager` only uses `ETag` for interrupted downloads -- it does not store `ETag` information indefinitely.

Comment: In other words, I should (somehow) store this info and make decisions whether to execute requests or not by myself?

Comment: @efpies: You don't have much of a choice. If `ETag` comes down on an HTTP `HEAD` request, you could issue your own `HEAD` request via `HttpUrlConnection`, see if the file needs updating, and then conditionally set up the `DownloadManager.Request`.